# Haskell, implementing Monoids. What is Semigroup and why does it act so weird?

Tags: haskell, monoids, semigroup

I wanted to implement a Custom Datatype named ComplexNumber like this:
`data ComplexNumber a = C (a,a)`

Now I wanted to implement the Monoid Variable and define the binary mempty Element and the mappend like this:

```
instance Num a => Monoid (ComplexNumber a) where
    mempty = C (0,0)
    mappend = (C (a1, b1)) (C (a2, b2)) = C (a1 + a2, b1 + b2)
```

but this didn't work out, so tried to figure out why and came across Semigroup (which I still dont really understand) and came to a soloution that atleast compiles and seems to work with this:

```
instance Num a => Semigroup (ComplexNumber a) where
    (C (a1, b1)) <> (C (a2,b2)) = C (a1 + a2, b1 + b2)

instance Num a => Monoid (ComplexNumber a) where
    mempty = C (0,0)
```

The funny thing is, when i remove the implementation of Semigroup the programm doesn't compile anymore and gives me following error:

```
    * Could not deduce (Semigroup (ComplexNumber a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the instance declaration at Aufgabe_10.hs:9:10-42
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid (ComplexNumber a)'
  |
9 | instance Num a => Monoid (ComplexNumber a) where
  |
```

Why is that i can compile those two sections together, but when i remove the semigroup an error occurs ? And what in particular is this Semigroup thing

Comment: A Semigroup is like a Monoid but with no neutral element. Which is another way to say that a Monoid is a Semigroup with a neutral element. So the way to define a Monoid structure is to define a Semigroup structure and then add a neutral element on top of it  Which is what Haskell asks you to do.

Comment: Please be more specific than "this didn't work out". (There is an equals sign too many in your first attempt.)

Comment: There is already a standard [`Complex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Complex.html) type. Your `mappend` is available as `+`; or, if you must have `mappend` be that operation, then the standard [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum) newtype has an appropriate `Monoid` instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Semigroup` is just the class of all types that have an implementation of the `<>` operation, in a way so that it's associative (i.e. that `a<>(b<>c) ≡ (a<>b)<>c`, which does hold true for your complex numbers if we disregard small floating-point deviations).

`Monoid` is the class of of semigroups which additionally have a neutral element `mempty`, i.e. an element that always fulfills `mempty <> a ≡ a <> mempty ≡ a` (also true for complex numbers with addition and zero).
This would be a nonsensical requirement for a type that doesn't even have the `<>` operation, i.e. that doesn't have a `Semigroup` instance. This is expressed by `Semigroup` being a *superclass* of `Monoid`, and thus it's impossible to have a type which is an instance of `Monoid` but not of `Semigroup`.

*Historically,* `Semigroup` and `Monoid` were separate classes, with the older `Monoid` shipping its own `mappend` operation that is the equivalent to the modern `<>`. Some older books / tutorials are still based on this old class hierarchy.
But because there are a bunch of types that are *only* semigroups, but not monoids, the class hierarchy was changed.

Answer (score 5):

A [*monoid* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) is a [*semigroup* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) with identity: it has an [*identity element e* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for which the associative binary operation *⊕* will *x ⊕ e = e ⊕ x = x* for all elements *x* in the set. Every *monoid* is thus a *semigroup*, since a *semigroup* is an algebraic structure with an associative binary operator *⊕* for which the same properties thus hold as in a monoid, except that there is no need for an identity element *e*.

Since `base-4.9.0.0`, a [**`Semigroup`** class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) has been introduced, but then `Semigroup` and [**`Monoid`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monoid) did not "live together". Since it does not make much sense to define a different binary operator for the `Semigroup` than for the `Monoid` instance (since that would likely introduce confusion), since `base-4.11.0.0`, `Semigroup` is a *superclass* of `Monoid`. Indeed, [`Monoid` is defined as <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monoid):

> ```
> class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
>     # …
> ```

This means that in order to make something an instance of `Monoid`, it has to be an instance of `Semigroup` as well. The [**`mappend :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mappend) will automatically link to the implementation of [**`(<>) :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--62-) and will, likely, eventually be removed.

You thus can no longer define an instance of `Monoid` without defining an instance of `Semigroup`. But you can "mechanically" create an instance from an old instance of `Monoid`, since you simply move the implementation of `mappend` from the `Monoid` instance to the instance for `Semigroup`.